# Interactive Graph Display in Ionic/Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, spring-boot, ionic-framework, graph

I have to create an interactive line graph that has entities at some points on the line which should be expandable. For example, if one was to hover over a dot that is on the line, a comment box should appear detailing the information about that specific dot. This is for a web app that is written in Ionic/Angular.js along with Spring-boot on the backend. What libraries can I use to create such a graph?

Comment: see http://www.sitepoint.com/15-best-javascript-charting-libraries/

Comment: or: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_charting_frameworks

Answer (score 0):

I have used http://www.chartjs.org/ in my Ionic app. It also has a wrapper for Angular: http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/.

A good tutorial about all this, from Nic Raboy: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/08/using-charts-in-your-ionic-framework-mobile-app/